# Проверить вхождение строки в List

Tags: c#, list

Есть класс DB. Как проверить входит ли определенная строка в `List<DB>`. Не хотелось бы загромождать код двойным циклом, чтобы определить вхождение строки. Есть ли более элегантное решение? `lambda`-выражения например*

```
class DB
{
    public string prelandingCard { get; set; } 
    public List<Pages> prePages { get; set; }
}

internal class Pages
{
    public string prePageCard { get; set; } страницы
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
List<DB> list = ...;
string targetString = ...;

bool isStringInList = list.Any(
    db =>
        db.prePages.Any(p => p.prePageCard == targetString) ||
        db.prelandingCard == targetString
);
```

хотя по-хорошему этот код должен быть разнесен по разным классам:

```
class DB
{
    public string prelandingCard { get; set; } 
    public List<Pages> prePages { get; set; }
    public bool HasString(string targetString)
    {
        return prePages.Any(p => p.prePageCard == targetString) ||
            prelandingCard == targetString;
    }
}
```

...

```
bool isStringInList = list.Any(
    db => db.HasString(targetString)
);
```

Comment: вы ведь проверяете prePages, а если совпадения есть в prelandingCard ?

Comment: @Radzhab добавьте `||`

Comment: Cannot resolve sumbol Any

Comment: @Radzhab `using System.Linq;`

Comment: оно по дефолту стоит

Comment: @Radzhab чуть опечатался - писал код прямо в форме ответа. подправил

Answer (score 3):

Можно так:

```
List<DB> list = new List<DB>();
//заполняем
string searchString = "some value";

if (list.Exists(db => db.prelandingCard == searchString || db.prePages.Exists(p => p.prePageCard == searchString)))
    Console.WriteLine("Yeah, db contain search string");
```

Можно и через `Any`, как предложил товарищ Выше:

```
List<DB> list = new List<DB>();
//заполняем
string searchString = "some value";
if (list.Any(db => db.prelandingCard == searchString || db.prePages.Any(p => p.prePageCard == searchString)))
    Console.WriteLine("Yeah, db contain search string");
```